# Opaque form overlay with yes no buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I have a site written in php and using basic HTML and CSS which consists of an input form followed by two pages.

The first has a question and yes/no buttons which then leads to the next page - a detailed display of information.

The powers that be have asked that somehow these two pages merge into one.  Their argument is that people might be put off by the first form and not bother proceeding to the second.

On the other hand, it is essential that somehow or other the user is forced to respond to the yes/no question before viewing the information page.

I thought that a possible solution could be to display the information page but overlay it with the yes/no page in such a way that the user sees there is information to view but can't actually see it clearly till he clicks either button.

I have searched and founds bits and pieces that may be relevant but I just do not have the knowledge to put it all together.  There is mention of javascript and jquery but unfortunately my knowledge of both extends to being able to paste it into my php code when told where to put it.

Any guidance on this or an other solution to achieve this would be most welcome.

Comment: *"but unfortunately my knowledge of both extends to being able to paste it into my php code when told where to put it"* - Therein lies the problem then.  You are being asked to use technologies with which you are not familiar.  So now is the time to familiarize yourself with them.  Start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript, jQuery, CSS, look for examples of "modal dialogs" in JavaScript (jQuery or otherwise), etc.  As a programmer, your employer probably expects you to do more than copy/paste text that's given to you.

Comment: Point taken as it was meant - constructively.  Thank you.  Had I been actually employed to do this I would have been fired long ago :)  

This is a new venture where we are trying, on a shoe-string, to develop a prototype which works, but is not necessarily a real 'pro' site.

The site works and we have a prospective client interested in the service it provides. He is the one who asked for this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some more hunting and have managed to created a php demo of what satisfies my question, based on code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842653/how-to-open-a-pop-up-when-page-loads-using-jquery) and include my version below for anyone else looking for such a solution.

```
<?php 
/*
Demo code based on <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842653/how-to-open-a-pop-up-when-page-loads-using-jquery>

The demo demonstrates the display of a page which is then overlaid (fade-in) with a permanent
pop-up that requests a user response (yes/no). The pop-up fades when the user responds.

The pop-up appears if $_SESSION['PopUpDone'] is NOT set. If it is set to any value then the 
pop-up code is not generated.

When the user responds then $_SESSION['PopUpDone'] is set to the user input and the pop-up
will no longer appear.
*/
    session_start();
# Control the turning on/off of $_SESSION['PopUpDone']
# If script called with parameter ?p=1 then reset the session variable to start demo again
    if($_GET['p'] == '1') unset($_SESSION['PopUpDone']);
# Get the user's response and set the session variable
    if(isset($_POST['response'])) {$_SESSION['PopUpDone'] = $_POST['response'];}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pop-Up Demo</title>

 <style>
    /* ----- CSS ----- */
    #popup {
      display: inline-block;
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10%;
      left: 50%;
      padding: 1em;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      background: peachpuff;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px .5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    }
    #popup.hidden {display: none;}
    #popup.fade-in {opacity: 1;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Pop-Up Demo</h1>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<p>This is some page text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. This is some tage text. </p>
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['PopUpDone'])) {
        echo "
            <div id = 'popup' class = 'hidden'>
                <p>Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here</p>
                <form method='post' action='' name='addNew'>
                    <center>
                        <input class='YesNoPopUp' id='YesNoPopUp' type='submit' name='response' value='Yes'/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input class='YesNoPopUp' id='YesNoPopUp' type='submit' name='response' value='No'/>
                    </center>
                </form>
                <p>Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here Put some text here</p>
            </div>
            <script>
            /* ----- JavaScript ----- */
            window.onload = function () {
              /* Cache the popup. */
              var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
              /* Show the popup. */
              popup.classList.remove('hidden');
              /* Fade the popup in */
              setTimeout(function(){popup.classList.add('fade-in')});
              /* Close the popup when a city is selected. */
              document.getElementById('YesNoPopUp').onchange = function () {
                 /* Fade the popup out */
                 popup.classList.remove('fade-in');
                 /* Hide the popup. */
                 setTimeout(function(){popup.classList.add('hidden')}, 300);
              };
            };
            </script>
        ";
    }
?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have discovered that this code totally fails to do anything with the pop-up-overlay when run from IE 11.  It displays the background and that is it.  Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: After some further research I discovered that IE was giving a syntax error on the two 'setTimeout' lines.  After changing them it works also on IE.  So all is well after all.